# how to append string to configuration variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

i have configuration variables in `config/application.rb` file as follows,

```
config.user1= 'http://localhost:3001/user1'
config.user2= 'http://localhost:3002/user2'
config.user3= 'http://localhost:3003/user1'
config.user4= 'http://localhost:3004/user2'
```

I wanted to get the configuration variables dynamically as follows,

```
a='.user1'
def config_d(a)     
 @b='Rails.configuration'+@a
 puts @b  #out put should be value of configuration variables 'http://localhost:3001/user1'
end
```

i have to pass `a` dynamically to the method as `config_d(user1)` for example

`config(user1)` should return `http://localhost:3001/user1`

`config(user2)` should return `http://localhost:3002/user2`

suggest me any technique to get the value of configuration from the string or hash or any other data structures.

thanks in advance,
Suresh

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to get absolute value of `@a`. There are few methods available in rails for this purpose such as `eval()` Try following:

```
def config_d(a)     
@b=Rails.configuration.eval(a)
puts @b  
end
```

following are few other methods which also serves the same purpose:

```
1.eval()
2.instance_eval() 
3.send()
4.public_send() 
5.method()
```

Hope this is helpful